# fbox does not produce the expected output

Tags: boxes, output, xepersian

Since I have had several issues using algorithm package for algorithms in my documents (due to using xepersian), I decided to have my algorithms as figures instead. So, in the following MWE I tried my algorithm to look like what it should but the border I defined is not showed as expected and the bullet points are showed out of the box. (see output image)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xepersian}
 %\usepackage{./styles/tempfix}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{B Nazanin}
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=2]{IranNastaliq}
\defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1]{B Titr}
\defpersianfont\traffic[Scale=1]{B Traffic}
\deflatinfont\calibri{Calibri}

\begin{document}
    % News Commands
    \newsavebox\mybox
    \newenvironment{myfbox}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule)}
    }{%
    \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}%
    \vskip10pt
    \noindent
    \fbox{\usebox\mybox}%
    \vskip10pt
    }
    \newenvironment{myshadowbox}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-\shadowsize)}
    }{%
    \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}%
    \vskip10pt
    \noindent
    \shadowbox{\usebox\mybox}%
    \vskip10pt
    }
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{myfbox}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{هدف: }  محاسبه‌ی نمایش تُنُک $y$ برحسب اتم‌های $D$
    \item \textbf{مقداردهی اولیه:} $r^0=y$ و $x^0=0$
    \item \textbf{شروع الگوریتم:}  قرار بده $k=1$ و گام‌های زیر را تا رسیدن به شرط توقف انجام بده:
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item محاسبه‌ی همبستگی اتم‌ها با باقی‌مانده: $c^k=D^T r^{k-1}$
    \item انتخاب بهترین اتم: $i^k=\arg\max_i |c_i^k|$
    \item به‌روز کردن نمایش تُنُک: $x_{i^k}^k=x_{i^k}^{k-1}+c_{i^k}^k$
    \item به‌روز کردن باقی‌مانده: $r^k=r^{k-1}-c_{i^k}^k d_{i^k}$
    \item چک کردن شرط توقف: اگر شرط توقف برآورده نشده است، قرار بده $k=k+1$ و برگرد به گام 1
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{خروجی:} $x^k$
\end{itemize}
\end{myfbox}
\caption{الگوریتم جستجوی تطابق \lr{(MP)}.}
\label{fig: mp}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

So, what am I doing wrong? 
[image]

Comment: I can't compile the file you posted because I don't have tempfix or the font.

Comment: @JPi: http://www.fontyab.com/wp-content/uploads/Far_Traffic.zip and http://www.fontyab.com/wp-content/uploads/Far_TitrBd.zip

Comment: I guess tempfix is not required.

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence. \argg`

Comment: I changed a few things in my code but forgot to change it here as well, sorry! @salimbou

Comment: I think this is due to RTL mode, just add `\leavevmode` before itemize environment.   It can be incorporated in the definition of `myfbox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Just add `\leavevmode` in the definition of `\myfbox` like this

```
\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{myfbox}{%
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr(\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule)}
\leavevmode}{%
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}%
\vskip10pt
\noindent
\fbox{\usebox\mybox}%
\vskip10pt
}
```